# Codename One, sending SMS on android issue

Tags: android, sms, codenameone

I am using Codename One to create an app for both Android and iOS which sends SMS messages. For the most part the app works well in both Android and iOS but I have discovered an intermittent situation which seems to crash the app in Android only. I can't recreate the fault in iOS. The issue only occurs once after installing the app and only occurs if the user makes the following steps:-

1. Launches the app for the first time and presses a button in the app to send an SMS.
2. The app then launches the default SMS app on the phone.
3. If the user then presses the home button on the mobile phone the app closes as it should but if they then open our app it opens with just a white screen and you can't do anything. The only option is to force close the app and relaunch it.

If the user doesn't press the home button and instead either uses the back button or the send button in the SMS app it returns to our app and works as it should and then if you press a button in the app to again send another SMS and use the home button the problem doesn't happen. It seems to only happen when you first install the app.

Could anyone suggest a cause and possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Does this happen on a specific version of Android or were you able to create it with several versions/devices? This sounds like a problem with the intent stack on Android... Try reproducing this with logging connected either via a cable or the native logging cn1lib to see if theres a printout with an exception.

Comment: Thanks @Shai, I tested on Android 8.0.0 on two devices but I will also try on others. I tried connecting with cable to Android studio following the instruction video 'Debug a Codename one Application on an Android device' for importing the source but had some problems. It says 'Not found' for the attr/attr/cn1Style in values, values-v11 & values-v21.xml. I am using studio version 3.4.1 and Gradle 5.1.1. I have tried different Gradles and build tools and also your tip on include source with Android studio but always have this same issue. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to run with Android studio. You can just run the device monitor and execute the APK built with the server to see the logs. See this, it's slightly out of date but still has a lot: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-include-source-android-studio-3.html

Comment: Thanks Shai. I have used the device monitor to collect information. What I can see is that when pressing the home button while the app has passed control to the SMS messaging app closes the app but doesn’t run the stop or destroy methods which I think is correct. But when clicking the icon to open the app again it runs the start method which I think is incorrect. When it works correctly it doesn’t run the start method, instead opens still in the SMS app and pressing the back button returns you to the app without running start.

Comment: That's incorrect, if stop isn't invoked but start is invoked again something went wrong. is this something that happens consistently? If so please file an issue so we can look into it: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new